# Finding the mistake in a new way of generating FSMs from regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

As described e.g. [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.5077&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (see pp. 2-3) a final state machine can be easily constructed from a regular expression. For the union of to expressions $e + f$ I need to look at the original way of construction and an alternative one (sorry for the graphics, I'm not an artist at all):

[image]

The new way of building the union merges the initial and final states of both subexpressions. It works properly if three invariants are respected for each of the two subexpressions $e$ and $f$:

1. There is exact one final state
2. There is no transition into the initial state ($\forall q \in Q.\forall a \in \Sigma \cup \{\lambda\} : q_0 \not\in \delta(q,a)$)
3. There is not transition out of the final state ($\forall a \in \Sigma \cup \{\lambda\} : \delta(q_f,a) = \emptyset$)

What I need to show is:
A FSM constructed using the "new" way does not recognize $L(E_e) \cup L(E_f)$ if (only)

- i) the second invariant is not followed
- ii) the third invariant is not followed

I tried to build a lot of FSM's, but I don't get why merging the initial and final states may lead to a FSM that doesn't recognizes a language if there are transitions into the inital or out of the final state.

Could you please help me to find FSMs for i) and ii)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The diagrams look [a little bit](https://www.stanford.edu/group/aha/cgi-bin/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/fsm.jpeg) like *the* [FSM](http://www.venganza.org/).

Comment: @Asaf: Aha! Thank you: you’ve just explained a popular culture reference that I ran into a while back.

Comment: Pastafarianism!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that I’ve a one-state machine $E_a$ that recognizes $a^*$ and another, $E_b$, that recognizes $b^*$; combining them in the second way would result in a one-state machine that recognized $(a\lor b)^*$, not $a^*\lor b^*$. This violates both (2) and (3), but you can use similar ideas to show that violating either of them individually can produce undesired results.

Comment: thank you, that helped me a lot. Nevertheless how do I create an FSM that violates only (3)? If I'm not allowed to go back to the initial state how can I affect $E_b$ from $E_a$?

Comment: @muffel: Suppose that $E_e$ is a three-state machine for $ab^+$, where the acceptor state loops on $b$, and $E_f$ is a three-state machine for $ba^+$ of the same design. If you combine them in the second way, what language does the resulting machine recognize? You even have problems if only one of them loops: what happens if $E_f$ accepts $ba$?

Comment: great, thanks! You saved my day! ;)